# Solution of second order differential equation with singularities at 0,1, and ∞

Tags: differential-equations, hypergeometric-functions

I am trying to solve the following equation;
$$
U''+\left( \frac{1}{t}+\frac{3}{t-1}\right)U'+\left(\frac{1}{t}+C\right)\frac{U}{t(t-1)}=0
$$
where U is a function of t and C is constant.
The above equation is similar to a form of Riemann equation.

Could anyone please provide any support on how the above equation can be solved. I am trying to obtain the solution in form of hyper-geometric series.

Comment: Using  [Riemann P-function Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%27s_differential_equation)
I am trying to transform this to a [Solvable Hypergeoemtric Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Transformation_formulas)
But I am facing problems in this, not sure if I am doing the right transformation.

Comment: The ***P-function*** of the above equation is 
$$
U=P\left\{ \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & \infty & 1 \\
+1 & \beta_1 & 0 & ;t \\
-1 & \beta_2 & -2 \end{array} \right\}
$$

Where β1 and β2 depends on C and can be calcualted by solving $$\beta^2-3\beta+C=0$$

The above needs to be transformed to a P-function for a [solvable hypergeometric form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#The_hypergeometric_differential_equation) which is of form
$$
w=P\left\{ \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & \infty & 1 \\
0 & a & 0 & ;z \\
1-c & b & c-a-b \end{array} \right\}
$$

Please advise if this can be achieved.

Comment: As I said, this is NOT a hypergeometric equation. Forget about P-function.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre. I was just posting what I found. I am looking into what you have suggested and hope to find the answer soon.

Comment: Apologies, I missed a few terms in the equation. It does represent a confluent Heun equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is more useful than the *Maple* solution given earlier, but Wolfram *Mathematica* finds a slightly different solution in terms of associated Legendre functions:

$$U(t) = \frac{1}{1-t} \left( k_1 P_\ell^2(2t-1) + k_2 Q_\ell^2(2t-1) \right)$$

Here, $k_1$ and $k_2$ are constants of integration, and $P_\ell^m$ and $Q_\ell^m$ are the associated Legendre functions of the [first](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) and [second](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreFunctionoftheSecondKind.html) kinds, with $\ell = \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{9-4 C}-1\right)$.

Comment: Curious, it did not find this solution for me :(

Comment: @IgorRivin Interesting, what solution does it find for you? I'm using version 10.1 on Windows.

Comment: Ah, it works. That was pilot error (since the pilot was very under slept at the time...)

Comment: The above solution can be obtained by the following two substitution
$$
U=\frac{Y}{1-t} 
$$
 and 
$$
w = 2t-1
$$

Answer (score 5):

This is not a hypergeometric equation (singularity at infinity is irregular). It can be reduced to the prolate spheroid equation. (Also known as confluent Heun equation).
See the references in Wikiedia,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolate_spheroidal_wave_function

Comment: This may be another form of the equation, but I am unable to see how it can be solved. If possible could you point some literature in this direction.

Comment: Wikipedia article on "Prolate spheroidal wave" has literature. Solutions are NOT hypergeometric functions, they are much more complicated.

Comment: Thanks I shall look in to those and will update here once I get something.

Comment: Note that many references in wiki is not active/ Also there is not a reference to the best book on the subject in Russian: Komarov,Ponamarev,Slavyanov. Spheroidal and Coulomb Spheroidal Functions, 1976.

Comment: Yes, of course, wiki references are inactive. But this site is for professional mathematicians, and professional mathematicians usually can find the references when the key word is given:-)

Answer (score 5):

Maple's solution is
$$ U \left( t \right) ={\frac {a{{\rm e}^{\sqrt {-C}t}}{\it HeunC}
 \left( 2\,\sqrt {-C},0,-2,1,-2,t \right) }{ \left( t-1 \right) ^{2}}}
+{\frac {b{{\rm e}^{\sqrt {-C}t}}{\it HeunC} \left( 2\,\sqrt {-C},0,-2
,1,-2,t \right) }{ \left( t-1 \right) ^{2}}\int \!{\frac { \left( t-1
 \right) {{\rm e}^{-2\,\sqrt {-C}t}}}{t \left( {\it HeunC} \left( 2\,
\sqrt {-C},0,-2,1,-2,t \right)  \right) ^{2}}}\,{\rm d}t}
$$

EDIT:  Note that this was for an earlier version of the problem with the differential equation
$$ U'' + \left(\dfrac{1}{t} + \dfrac{3}{t-1}\right) U' + \left(\dfrac{1}{t} + C\right) U = 0 $$
The equation has now been changed to 
$$  U'' + \left(\dfrac{1}{t} + \dfrac{3}{t-1}\right) U' + \left(\dfrac{1}{t} + C\right) \dfrac{U}{t(t-1)} = 0 $$
which does have hypergeometric solutions.

**Please:** In future, if you want to change a question, especially after answers have been posted, don't delete the original form of the question;  rather, add a new paragraph with the change.  Otherwise, the casual reader might think we've posted wrong answers.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I have to explore further on the above equation specially HeunC () function.

Comment: Information on the Heun DEs:
B. D. Sleeman & V. B. Kuznetsov,
*Digital Library of Mathematical Functions*.  Chapter 31, Heun Functions.
http://dlmf.nist.gov/31   "HeunC" is Maple-talk for a Heun confluent function.

Comment: See also http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=HeunC and in particular the References section.

Answer (score 1):

The given equation can be converted to a hyper-geometric equation by the following substitution,
$$
U = tY
$$
This gives,
$$
t(1-t)Y''+(c-(a+b+1)t)Y'-abY=0
$$
with
$$
c=3, a+b+1 = 6, ab=C+4
$$
The final solution Y(t) can then be obtained using the hyper-geometric series function and hence U(t) = t Y(t).

I appreciate all for their effort and help.